# How to check what frameworks and methods supported by winobjc

Tags: winobjc

I tried to port a sample iOS app with a UITableView to Windows 10. In which it tries to display 100 rows with each row contains label with value as row number. Here is the code

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name %ld", indexPath.row];
```

And when launched this app in windows10 i see only empty rows.
Does viewWithTag is supported?.
How do i check what api's and methods supported by winobjc? Is there any documentation available on this?

Answer (score 0):

I work on the iOS bridge project at Microsoft. The problem you're seeing here has to do with cell reuse identifiers, not viewWithTag. Our Xib2Nib tool handles converting Storyboards and Xibs when you run vsimporter. Currently, Xib2Nib does not support cell reuse identifiers defined in Storyboards (although it does support cell reuse identifiers in Xibs). So when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, the correct cell with your UILabel in it is not instantiated, which results in you getting blank cells.

There are a couple of potential solutions to this. You could build your layout programmatically in a UITableViewCell subclass and use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. You could also lay out your cell in its own xib file (separate from your Storyboard) and use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

In either case, you should [file an issue on the project on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/issues/new) if you'd like to see support for cell reuse identifiers in Storyboards – Github is the best way to get in touch with our team and informs all of our prioritization decisions.

More generally, you can see what's supported and not supported by the bridge in the Visual Studio debug console; when missing or stubbed APIs are called, you'll get a message with details. We're also working on tools that will make browsing the API surface area easier.

Thanks for checking out the project!